# Bootstrap 4 toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, bootstrap-4

I am building a simple vehicle inspection form and I would like to use checkboxes as buttons to capture `true`/`false` values.

This is supposed to be trivial using [Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons).

I would however like to adjust the default behaviour of the buttons; **to toggle between the `success` and `danger` classes to denote `true`/`false`.** And also in some cases to change the text of the button, eg. "Leaks" -> "No Leaks".

1. I have got the toggle working with the help of @Yass but I am not getting the correct `true`/`false` values when I submit the form. Even though the checkboxes are checked (`true`), the values are coming through as if they are `false`.
2. I'm not sure how to handle the change in text when toggling between the two states.

**Checkbox Buttons**

[image: Checkbox Buttons]

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <p class="font-weight-bold">Bonnet</p>
        <div data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="oil" checked="checked" autocomplete="off"> Oil
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="coolant" checked="checked" autocomplete="off"> Coolant
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="breakfluid" checked="checked" autocomplete="off"> Break Fluid
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="screenwash" checked="checked" autocomplete="off"> Screen Wash
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="noleaks" checked="checked" autocomplete="off"> No Leaks
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <p class="font-weight-bold">Outside</p>
        <div data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="tyres" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Tyres
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="wiperblades" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Wiper Blades
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="lights" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Lights
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="indicators" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Indicators
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="outcleanliness" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Cleanliness
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <p class="font-weight-bold">Inside</p>
        <div data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="horn" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Horn
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="breaks" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Breaks/Handbrake
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="seatbelt" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Seatbelt
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="windscreen" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Windscreen
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                <input type="checkbox" name="incleanliness" checked="checked" autocomplete="off">
                Cleanliness
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('label.btn').on('click', function() {
    //Find the child check box.
    var $input = $(this).find('input');

    $(this).toggleClass('btn-danger btn-success');
    //Remove the attribute if the button is "disabled"
    if ($(this).hasClass('btn-danger')) {
        $input.removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
        $input.attr('checked', '');
    }

    return false; //Click event is triggered twice and this prevents re-toggling of classes
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mstnorris/9fyzfu8w/

Comment: A live example of what you have so far would help. If that's not possible, how about your html layout and css?

Comment: @Yass I've updated my original question to add clarity. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution with pure Javascript. Add a hidden input associated to each button, and update hidden values each time the button is clicked.

HTML :

```
<!-- Visible button -->
<input onclick="toogleButton(this,'hiddenButton')" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" value="Toogle">
<!-- Hidden input -->
<input name="FM_city" id="hiddenButton" type="hidden" value="0"></input>
```

Javascript :

```
// Called when the button is clicked
function toogleButton(callingElement,hiddenElement)
{
    // Check the color of the button
    if (callingElement.classList.contains('btn-secondary'))
    {
        // If the button is 'unset'; change color and update hidden element to 1
        callingElement.classList.remove('btn-secondary');
        callingElement.classList.add('btn-success');
        document.getElementById(hiddenElement).value="1";
    }
    else 
    {
        // If the button is 'set'; change color and update hidden element to 0
        callingElement.classList.remove('btn-success');
        callingElement.classList.add('btn-secondary');
        document.getElementById(hiddenElement).value="0";
    }
}
```

When the form is submitted, process value of the hidden input. Note that you can easily change the text of the button with : `callingElement.value="New text here"`
Last remark : initial value of hidden elements must be in accordance with the initial color of the associated button.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the click event of the buttons, and toggle the checked value of the input using jQuery `.prop()` like this..

```
var $chk = $(this).find('[type=checkbox]');
$chk.prop('checked',!$chk.prop('checked'));
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/IeuO1fPf7H